# 'no module named atexit' when I run a program deployed using pyinstaller

Tags: pyinstaller

First of all, the machine is running Fedora 13 and the version of PyInstaller is 1.5.1

I did use --onefile when generate the spec.

I did not have any error with running 'import atexit' from within Python interpreter.

Here's the traceback from running the binary:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
File "/home/pyinstaller-1.5.1/iu.py", line 436, in importHook
 mod = _self_doimport(nm, ctx, fqname)
File "/home/pyinstaller-1.5.1/iu.py", line 495, in doimport
 mod = importfunc(nm)
File "/home/pyinstaller-1.5.1/iu.py", line 297, in getmod
 mod = owner.getmod(nm)
File "/home/pyinstaller-1.5.1/archive.py", line 468, in getmod
 return iu.DirOwner.getmod(self, self.prefix+'.'+nm)
File "/home/pyinstaller-1.5.1/iu.py", line 109, in getmod
 mod = imp.load_module(nm, fp, attempt, (ext, mode, typ))
File "/home/pyinstaller-1.5.1/iu.py", line 436, in importHook
 mod = _self_doimport(nm, ctx, fqname)
File "/home/pyinstaller-1.5.1/iu.py", line 505, in doimport
 mod = director.getmod(nm)
File "/home/pyinstaller-1.5.1/iu.py", line 297, in getmod
 mod = owner.getmod(nm)
File "/home/pyinstaller-1.5.1/iu.py", line 109, in getmod
 mod = imp.load_module(nm, fp, attempt, (ext, mode, typ))
File "/home/pyinstaller-1.5.1/iu.py", line 455, in importHook
 raise ImportError, "No module named %s" % fqname
ImportError: No module named atexit
```

Answer (score 6):

I solved this by adding 'import atexit' into the source code. Hope this will help other people who have similar problems

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to add `--hidden-import=atexit` to PyInstaller arguments so that PyInstaller can know it's an import of your app and therefore include it in the executable.

More documentation can be found here: https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html#cmdoption-hidden-import